# No function to enter value in a different base?

Tags: number-bases

I notice that there is a syntax to enter a numeric literal in a different base, for example:

```
In[8]:= 5^^1000000000000101
Out[8]= 30517578151
```

However, there does not seem to be any function to enter a number in a different base. Since, it seems practically every operation in Mathematical has a corresponding function, this seems strange. Also, the documentation for ^^ is hidden in the BaseForm function's documentation, and is just barely mentioned. It is not listed as an operator at all.

This weird syntax is a problem for me. For example, I tried to display a number in different bases like this:

```
Map[(#^^1000000000000101) &, Range[2, 10]]
```

and it gives an error.

Answer (score 1):

`FromDigits` can do the job:

```
FromDigits["1000000000000101", Range[2, 10]]

(* {32773, 14348917, 1073741841, 30517578151, 470184984613,
    4747561509993, 35184372088897, 205891132094731, 1000000000000101} *)
```

Comment: Yes, I knew about this command but it seemed like "cheating" because you are actually treating the number as a string. It does not actually handle the value numerically the way ^^ does.

Comment: `^^` also treats the digits as a string even though syntactically it allows us to omit the quotes.  Consider: `16^^face == FromDigits["face", 16]`.

Comment: Or, with a number use `FromDigits[IntegerDigits[1000000000000101], Range[2, 10]]`